# Slope between two points - Vectors

Tags: vectors

I have two vector points, $\langle 1,3,7 \rangle$ and $\langle 23,-5,10 \rangle$. Point $1$ is at $t=13$ and Point $2$ is at $t=81$. I know how to find the slope between two vector points when $t=0$ and $t=1$ (namely $\langle 1,3,7 \rangle + t\langle 22,-8,3 \rangle$), how do you do it with times like this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector between point 1 and point 2 is $\langle23,-5,10\rangle - \langle1,3,7,\rangle = \langle22,-8,3\rangle$.
The time between point 1 and point 2 is $t=81-13 = 68$.
This means that over $68$ units of time, the point traveled over $\langle22,-8,3\rangle$.
It follows so that over $1$ unit of time, the point will travel $\frac1{68}\langle22,-8,3\rangle = \langle\frac{11}{34},-\frac{2}{17},\frac3{68}\rangle$.

And that is your "slope", aka "direction vector!"

Your line, of course, will have the equation $\langle1,3,7\rangle + t\langle\frac{11}{34},-\frac{2}{17},\frac3{68}\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a vector equation of the line that hits the target points at the targeted time, then we need to make a small adjustment to $t$

$\langle 1,3,7 \rangle + \frac {t-13}{81-13}\langle 22,-8,3 \rangle$

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1064496)

Comment: @amWhy You don't think that is satisfactory?  It takes the work the OP has already done, and shows the step he need to take to get from where he is across the finish line.